# Sort 2d arrays Using Arrays.sort in java

Tags: java

Can anyone tell what is the difference between these lines?

```
Arrays.sort(pairs, (a, b) -> a[0] - b[0])
Arrays.sort(pairs, (a, b) -> a[1] - b[1]);
```

Comment: First line will not compile because of lack of `;` at the end. But if we add that `;` it will try to sort arrays based on values of their first column (accessed via `[0]`). Second will try to sort based on values of second column (accessed via `[1]`).

Comment: Also, comparing the values using subtraction may fail if an integer overflow/underflow occurs, so it's better to use `Integer::compare`

Answer (score 1):

The first sorts based on the first element of the arrays that are being sorted, and the other sorts based on the next element.

If the input was:

```
[2, 33], [4, 22], [3, 11]
```

The first would produce

```
[2, 33], [3, 11], [4, 22]
```

and the second would produce

```
[3, 11], [4, 22], [2, 33]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code. It looks that the first line will not execute. Because it is missing the terminator.

```
Arrays.sort(pairs, (a, b) -> a[0] - b[0]);
```

And the second line will run and it gives the output according to your input.

```
Arrays.sort(pairs, (a, b) -> a[1] - b[1]);
```